# Cannot read property 'setTargetNode' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting Cannot read property 'setTargetNode' of undefined error when I pulled the working code from GitHub and running it locally. But the same code was deployed in server and it is working without any error and the code that is working in the local environment is not working on the server and I get the same error(Cannot read property 'setTargetNode' of undefined ). I don't have any idea about it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you should provide proper details, add code block of what you have done, like that.

Comment: Discussion at https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper/issues/294

Comment: Reactstrap version upgraded, when we deploy new code in server it installed the new version of react-strap so the error came in server. but in my local-code, i had already node modules it worked fine. Try to delete node modules and re-install them then you will find the root-cause. for me issue was at header Dropdown Toggle